# Confused about pipe implementation

Tags: c, unix, pipe

One implementation of a pipe is:

```
#define STD_INPUT 0
#define STD_OUTPUT 1
pipeline(char *process1, char *process2)
{
    int fd[2];

    pipe(&fd[0]);
    if (fork() != 0) {
        /* The parent process executes these statements. */
        close(fd[0]);
        close(STD_OUTPUT);
        dup(fd[1]);
        close(fd[1]);    /* this file descriptor not needed anymore */
        execl(process1, process1, 0);
    }
    else {
        /* The child process executes these statements. */
        close(fd[1]);
        close(STD_INPUT);
        dup(fd[0]);
        close(fd[0]);   /* this file descriptor not needed anymore */
        execl(process2, process2, 0);
   }
}
```

I am confused by the use of the two statements which follow each dup call, respectively.

```
close(fd[1]);    /* this file descriptor not needed anymore */
```

and

```
close(fd[0]);   /* this file descriptor not needed anymore */
```

I am told the descriptors are no longer needed, but to me those descriptors represent each end of the pipe, so why are they no longer needed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `pipe` call returns both the read descriptor and the write descriptor for unidirectional communication. However, the writer does not need the read descriptor (`fd[0]`). And, the reader does not need the write descriptor (`fd[1]`). So, each process after the `fork` call closes the descriptor it does not need, and uses the descriptor that it does need.

So, the parent is the writer in your example. It closes the `fd[0]` first, and then closes `STD_OUTPUT`. It then duplicates `fd[1]`, which will now be in `STD_OUTPUT` since it is available. Since the output descriptor of the pipe is now duplicated, it is no longer needed either, so it is closed. Now, when the writer writes something to `STD_OUTPUT`, it will be writing to the output descriptor of the pipe.

The child, which is the reader, performs similar logic, but on the other descriptor. It first closes `fd[1]`, and then closes `STD_INPUT`. It then duplicates `fd[0]`, which results in the descriptor being in `STD_INPUT`. After being duplicated, the input descriptor of the the pipe is no longer needed, so it is closed. Now, when the reader reads something from `STD_INPUT`, it will be reading from the input descriptor of the pipe.

Comment: My apologies, the question was ambiguous, I have updated it.
I understand the first uses of close before dup, but not the second calls to close after dup.

Comment: @richard: You don't need two copies of the file descriptor, do you? Once you've duplicated it, you don't need the original.

Comment: I understand this now, I had misunderstood the example.
Thanks